# how to create empty c type array (or just one NULL value) in python?

Tags: python, c, opengl, ctypes

I was wondering whether (and how) one can create empty c type arrays in python. The following code works fine if I want to initialize an array with zeros:

```
from ctypes import *
data = [0 for i in xrange(10)]
a = ((c_float *10))(*data)
```

If data is a list of `None` values however, I get an error message:

```
data = [None for i in xrange(10)]
a = ((c_float *10))(*data)

TypeError:  float expected instead of NoneType instance
```

is there a way to initialize and array with NONEs or NULLs?

**EDIT 1:**
the reason why I want an array with None / Null is that I want to upload this array to the GPU. If I initialize my array with Zeros, then zeros will be rendered. However if I initialize it will NULL (as defined in c), nothing is rendered.

**EDIT 2:**
the reason for using `c_float` is that I need to cast my data to `c_float` in order for it to be compatible with opengl.

**EDIT 3:**
if `data` is made of zeros, then the following code will render me a bunch of points @ location 0 / 0. I was hoping that sending `NULL` values to the GPU will not result in any points being rendered.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)    
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(data), data)
glVertexPointer(n_COORDINATES_PER_VERTEX, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, len(data))
```

**EDIT 4:**
Another use-case when you might want to use `NULL` in python: according to the [opengl website](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object), the following is how to allocate memory on the GPU:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SizeInBytes, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

If I do this in my python code, I get the following error: `NameError: global name 'NULL' is not defined`

but there must be a way to do this in python, right?

Comment: AFAICT your question actually has nothing to do with arrays right? You just seem to be confused by the fact that you can't use None as a default value for a float. Trying that cast with None outside of an array fails, too. Why do you want to use None instead of 0.0 anyway?

Comment: @Paul I think the OP is asking something different. I think the OP is saying, "How do I take an array populated with NoneTypes (or something similar) and get a ctypes array that is full of NULLs?" I think the reference to `c_float` in the last line of the code is just the OP's naive first try. I think changing that instance of `c_float` to something that works would be the right answer here, *not* changing the demand for an array of NoneTypes (unless ctypes literally cannot allow that at all).

Comment: What do you mean "zeros will be rendered"? When you transfer the host variable to the device, what is happening to 'render' it. Also, are you using PyCUDA?

Comment: I was under impression that NULL is 0 ? http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null, are you taking about array being NULL instead of containing NULL values?

Comment: @memyself I'm not sure that a NULL array is a good idea here. It might work OK, but if anything operates by trying to dereference something, it would be easy for a segfault to occur. Why not add one extra unit to the array that you ship, say the 0th entry is 1 if the array is OK to process from entries 1 to End, otherwise if entry 0 is equal to 0, then don't do the rendering you listed above. I don't know if this dramatically throws off your thread striding or not though.

Comment: Another idea: what happens if you send it an array of negative numbers? Does it render somewhere on the screen?

Comment: @EMS well, depends on the view. but since I'm looking at points in the range of -x to +x, the points will be rendered.

Comment: This just seems unusual to me. Any program that needs an array of floats would have to initialize it somehow. You're suggesting that as soon as it is initialized, it is sent to some rendering code, and there's no opportunity to intercept it, check if it's been properly initialized or is just all zeros, do some initializing, and *then* send it to the rendering code?

Comment: @EMS see my EDIT4. The code is from the opengl website and is used to allocate memory on the GPU. but since `NULL` doesn't exist in python, I can not call this code.

Comment: I'm really surprised there is no interface between PyCUDA and OpenGL. In PyCUDA you can easily allocate device variables in a number of ways, and then use CUDA commands like cuda.mem_alloc() and cuda.memcpy_htod() to move things to the device. It would seem that some combination of this should work. But perhaps getting PyCUDA to use OpenGL commands is a pain. I'm not very familiar with OpenGL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `c_float` has no equivalent value for 'None', so you can't store `None` in a `c_float`.

See [the table in the python `ctypes` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) - there are some types that support `None` - but none that support both floats and `None`.

You will have to use an alternate data type, record `None` values separately somehow, or find a way of representing `None` as a float that works for your application.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to have null value for c_float? in C null is zero, so basically you want to have a array of zeroes, which you can do by converting array of Nones e.g.

```
from ctypes import *
data = [None for i in xrange(10)]
# convert to zeroes
data = [i or 0 for i in data]
a = ((c_float *10))(*data)
```

Edit: looks like you don't want to draw anything if values are None, in that case there is no way to have c_floats with 'nothing' as NULL is 0, best way would be to set array as NULL and not draw anything using `if` condition

Comment: This is precisely the first block of code the OP lists, except simpler than yours. The OP specifically doesn't want to populate an array of zeros and then assign a c-style array based on those zeros.

Comment: EMS that is what I am explaining that there is no way you will have to convert values which make sense for c_float, even in python you can't do `float(None)`

Comment: Right, so the problem here is not that the OP *must* use c_float, it's that we need to find another primitive type in ctypes that allows for NULL. You seem stuck on the use of `a = ((c_float *10))(*data)`, but the OP doesn't seem to say that this is what must happen.

Comment: @EMS let OP say that he doesn't want array of c_float, from question it looks to me that he wants an array of c_floats

Comment: It doesn't look that way to me. It looks like OP expected that c_float would be OK to handle NULLs, but failing that, something else is needed to handle NULLs instead. The OP showed the naive first try, and is clearly well aware that making the list into 0's would make it work, but doesn't want a list of 0's.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal I agree with @EMS - It appears he wants to differentiate between `0` and `None`, which is impossible with `c_float`s, hence my answer.

Comment: @EMS so OP after all wants float array, anyway his question seems to be misleading with X-Y problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass a NULL array pointer via ctypes?  Use `None` for NULL.  You can't have a NULL float value, but you can have a NULL float array pointer.

And like @Anurag said, if you don't want to draw anything, don't call the function to draw.

Comment: when I try to use `None` I get the `TypeError:  float expected instead of NoneType instance` error. see my original posting.

Comment: EDIT4 you wanted to pass NULL there.  Post the C function definition you are trying to call and your Python ctypes code that tries to call it. If it takes a float, that`s all you can pass.  No None/NULL allowed.

Comment: The gl functions take a void pointer. If you've declared it to take a float with ctypes that's wrong.